# Ghost.py and proxy

Tags: python, qt, pyside, ghost.py

Is anyone able to explain how to make [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) work with a proxy? I've checked out the code but it's not there.

Comment: do you have any update on `set_proxy`? It remains very unclear on my side. If you want to specify one, I do something like `ghost=Ghost(wait_timeout=20)` then `ghost.set_proxy(type_='http', host="http://myproxy.net", port=7676)` but `page, res = ghost.open()` gives a `page=None` result

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Are you sure of the proxy and it's port, to know that they are working?

Comment: Yes completely sure since they are working when I use `urllib2` to scrap some static data with proxy. So the proxy and port are correct, I guess I am doing something wrong with `ghost` but do not know what ...

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I don't have any working proxy to test it out now. I would do that as soon as I'm able to and then get back to you with the results. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it in the ghost.py file. They did a very good job in it. It's a method on line 835, as set_proxy(). It's just how to use it that I'm yet to try out:

```
def set_proxy(self, type_, host='localhost', port=8888, user='',
        password=''):
    """Set up proxy for FURTHER connections.

    :param type_: proxy type to use: \
        none/default/socks5/https/http.
    :param host: proxy server ip or host name.
    :param port: proxy port.
    """
    _types = {
        'default': QNetworkProxy.DefaultProxy,
        'none': QNetworkProxy.NoProxy,
        'socks5': QNetworkProxy.Socks5Proxy,
        'https': QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy,
        'http': QNetworkProxy.HttpCachingProxy
    }

    if type_ is None:
        type_ = 'none'
    type_ = type_.lower()
    if type_ in ['none', 'default']:
        self.manager.setProxy(QNetworkProxy(_types[type_]))
        return
    elif type_ in _types:
        proxy = QNetworkProxy(_types[type_], hostName=host, port=port,
            user=user, password=password)
        self.manager.setProxy(proxy)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unsupported proxy type:' + type_ \
        + '\nsupported types are: none/socks5/http/https/default')
```

What I don't understand now is what "QNetworkProxy.DefaultProxy" means. It's said to be the default proxy. So, what's the default proxy?

Comment: did you finally got how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

If in Ghost.py the way of making tcp connections based on Qt api, then you may use Qt/PySide api, see QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(). Otherwise, if Ghost.py not using Qt Api, but for example curl libe, then you try to set environment variable "http_proxy"

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says that QNetworkProxy.DefaultProxy: 
Proxy is determined based on the application proxy set using setApplicationProxy()
So if proxy is set by QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(), then the call set_proxy('default') will make to use it 
(it will pass the proxy to self.manager, which I guess is the QNetworkAccessManager object).

Comment: So, does this mean that if I set an https proxy without specifying that the QNetworkAccessManager will understand that its https?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code. It works for me,

```
from ghost import Ghost, Session
ghost = Ghost()
with ghost.start():
    session = Session(ghost)
    session.wait_timeout = 999
    session.set_proxy('http', str(ip), int(port), str(username), str(password))
    page, resource = session.open(url)
    print session.content # Prints html content
    print page.headers, page.url, page.http_status
```

The ghost object has only one method i.e start(). Rest of them are defined as methods of Session class.

Comment: what was the form of the proxy you mentionned? `"http://myproxy.net"` for example or simply `"myproxy.net"` ?

Comment: The proxy I used was an ip address like 192.168.1.1 and its port. I am not sure if myproxy.net works.