# Use proxy with ghost

Tags: python, proxy, ghost.py

it has already discussed in this question [ghost.py and proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263960/ghost-py-and-proxy) but the answer does not appear clear to me.

I have ghost installed and also have a proxy( the host is `host=http://XXXXXXXX` and `port=7676`).

```
from ghost import Ghost

url     = "https://www.google.co.uk"
host    = 'http://XXXXXXXX'
port    = 7676
ghost   = Ghost(wait_timeout=20)
ghost.set_proxy(type_='http', host=host, port=port)
ghost.open(url)
html = ghost.content
```

But I get an empty `html` string. I also tried with `ghost.set_proxy(type_='https', host=host, port=port)` but it fails (`html` string remains empty).

When home with no proxy, (and thus without the line `ghost.set_proxy(type_='http', host=host, port=port)`), it works.

I am udner a `Win 64 Bits OS`, with the proxy already settled in `Advanced Settings`.
Would you have any idea of what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Most HTTP libraries use the proxy you specify in the corresponding environment variable; so running

```
export https_proxy="https://myproxy.com:7676"
```

should help (on unixoid systems, at least).

When you use something like `wget` to access the URL through a proxy, and still get an empty reply, make sure your proxy is configured correctly, you're using the right credentials, and your remote server is not behaving strangely with things that are behind a proxy (which I wouldn't assume with google ;).

EDIT: just realized: You're only setting a HTTPS proxy; some elements on the page you're requesting might be fetched via HTTP (not S), and without a proxy for that, this might fail.

Comment: But export is not a Python command? I am on Windows and already configure the proxy in advanced settings, but seems like Qt is not detecting it automatically.

Comment: That's why I recommended checking the proxy functionality with something "simpler" than ghost.py. Windows always lacks the most basic tools that everyone else's OSes come with, so most probably something based on `urllib2` in python would be a good test.

Comment: Nope, `urllib2` does not handle javascript and dynamic scrapping. The proxy works `with urllib2` with  `proxy_support=urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxies); opener=urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support); urllib2.install_opener(opener)`. But that's not the point. I am talking aobut `ghost.py` under - I should have mentionned it - a WinOS.

Comment: Hm, the point is that I was assuming that your empty reply stems from something that goes wrong long before the first line of html, javascript or whatever would be received, as misconfigured proxies are the nr. 1 error reason when one of my customers has a problem with our automated downloader.

Comment: It is sure it comes from the proxy, I clearly said it in the question.

Comment: "Empty html string" doesn't really indicate where the error happens.

Comment: If no proxy, html contains something. If there is a proxy, html contains nothing. So there's something wrong with my proxy setting, but no error is raised.